# Finding key in array that meets conditions

Tags: php, arrays, key

I'm trying to extract a key from an array that meets some criteria and I'm having problems filtering this array. This is a sample and the array can have much more elements. They will all have the same country, region and prefix. What can be different is update_status and activation_date.

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [country] => Country
        [region] => Region
        [prefix] => 12345
        [new_rate] => 0.2000
        [update_status] => 
        [activation_date] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [country] => Country
        [region] => Region
        [prefix] => 12345
        [new_rate] => 0.2000
        [update_status] => NEW
        [activation_date] => 2014-10-03 03:48:00
    )
```

What I need to find is the FIRST occurrence (key) where update_status IS NOT EMPTY (if exists). If the key when status is not empty doesn't exist, i need the LAST occurrence where the status is empty.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
$index = count($ARRAY) - 1;
foreach($ARRAY as $key=>$val){
    if(isset($val['update_status']) && !is_null($val['update_status'])){
        $index = $key;
        break;
    }
}
```

Does this work?

Comment: Yes Diogo. Nice and simple, exactly what i need. Problem solved.

Comment: @infinite don't forget to accept any of these answers if it indeed helped you, click the check on the left side of the answer

Comment: @Ghost, I absolutely won't. This is the reason i like stackoverflow. Sometimes we all stuck somewhere. Guys reply with new and fresh ideas. My solution was totally different, unnecessarily complex and I got lost. I've got answers which are doing exactly what i need and they can't be any simpler because they are the only proper logical solutions.

Answer (score 1):

```
$key = 0;
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($value["update_status"] != "") {
        break;
    }
}
```

`$key` will contain first the occurrence (or the last element of the array if it doesn't exist)

(If a foreach loop ends, the `$key` and `$value` still have the values of the last iteration, so no problem.)

Comment: @Silva,@bwoebi Thank you guys for such an elegant solutions. Instead of this simple and elegant approach i almost got lost doing some complex filtering without a reel need. This is what i need.